# Altering menu local task title

Tags: 7, routes

I'm trying to override the title of a system provided local task. I have the following code which works for uid 1 but not authenticated users:

```
function test_controller_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  if ($root_path == 'user/%') {
    foreach($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $item) {
      if ($item['#link']['path'] == 'user/%/edit') {
        $data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]['#link']['title'] = t('Password and email address');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1140550) this is expected behaviour for the time being. Is there another way round this?

Answer (score 1):

i have an idea if you use string override module .this module provide the override  the local task menu.

http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for you digital, but the authenticated must have first the rights to modify their own account to see the local task. And the code below worked for me :

```
$pattern = '/^user/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $root_path)) {
  foreach($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $item){
    if(isset($item['#link']['path']) && $item['#link']['path'] == 'user/%/view'){
      $data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]['#link']['title'] = t('My personal tools');
    }
  }
}
```

I used a pattern so the title stays the same on each user's page.