# Arranging tab menus created by views module

Tags: 7, views

I've created 3 different view and added them to a tab menu.

now these 3 menu items are sorted alphabetically and the default tab menu is printed as middle item .

I wanted to sort them using menus but tab items doesn't exist there .

> How can I reorder tab items created by views module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a weight while editing the Views tab:
[image: Edit tab]. Higher weights will be moved to the back of the order. But since you cannot see the weights of the other tabs this can take quite a while to get right.

Better is to have a look at [Tab Tamer](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer)

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering,
>   hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab
>   labels.

Comment: totally forgot tab tamer ..

Comment: after these many years of this answer, it helped me to save me my time. changing the weight works for me...  Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the weight in [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7):

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()
*
* @param $data
* @param $router_item
* @param $root_path
*/
function HOOK_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  if ($root_path == 'admin/content') {
    // You add #weight here on item level not link level
    $data['tabs'][0]['output'][0]['#weight'] = '1000';
  }
}
```

For more code you can also look here: [Altering menu local task title](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39693/altering-menu-local-task-title)

Comment: isn't there any solution without coding? anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is 2 years ago, but this will help somebody looking for similar problem.

here you can see full code for creating menu tabs with weight. (just put weight in $items array under key)

```
$items['processing'] = array(
    //'title' => t('Create Menu Tab'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'access arguments' => array('dn_release'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'  => array('dn_wawi_release_form'),
  );

  $items['processing/order/release'] = array(
    'title' => 'Release orders',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'access arguments' => array('dn_release'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'  => array('dn_wawi_release_form'),
    'weight' => 1,
  );

  $items['processing/order/labels'] = array(
    'title' => 'Print labels',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'access arguments' => array('dn_wawi'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'  => array('dn_wawi_generate_tracking_form'),
    'weight' => 2,
  );
```